# Keras load_model with tf.keras.losses.LogCosh as custom_object

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss

I'm want to load my saved model and retrain it. However, I'm having problems to set the `custom_objects` parameter. The custom object is the  `tf.keras.losses.LogCosh` loss. My code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
import neptune.new as neptune
from tensorflow.keras.losses import LogCosh
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import losses_utils

logcosh = LogCosh(reduction= losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO, name= 'logcosh')
   
model = load_model('my_model.hdf5', custom_objects={'logcosh': LogCosh(reduction= losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO, name= 'logcosh')
})
```

The error is the following

```
ValueError: Unknown metric function: {'class_name': 'LogCosh', 'config': {'reduction': 'auto', 'name': <tensorflow.python.keras.losses.LogCosh object at 0x7f8e00d29400>}}
```

Comment: Can you add all imports to make the code runnable?

Comment: You are mixing imports between keras and tf.keras which is not supported and will not work.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I know it is not good, but I have train the model mixing them. How would you do it just using keras?

Comment: There is keras.losses.LogCosh, there is no need to mix (and as you see, that does not work).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks. I'll try it!

Comment: @MarlonTeixeira, Did you tried as suggested above?

Comment: @TFer2 I've ended up taking off this loss.